# Continue statement in Pl/sql

Tags: oracle

I am working Oracle 10g. I am running this pl/sql  block

```
Declare
cursor Get_Data is select * from employee for update;
data Get_Data%rowtype;

Begin

for data in Get_Data loop
  if(data.salary=5000) then 
  continue; 
  else 
   update employee set salary= salary+3000 where current of Get_Data;
  end if;
end loop;
end;
```

It is giving me this Error  : `identifier 'CONTINUE' must be declared`

please suggest me how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a note: `CONTINUE` is supported only in Oracle 11g.

Refer here: 
Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference 11g Release 1 (11.1) > What's New in PL/SQL? > [CONTINUE Statement](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/whatsnew.htm#CHDDIIJA)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Declare
    cursor Get_Data is select * from employee for update;
    data Get_Data%rowtype;

    Begin

    for data in Get_Data loop
      if(data.salary<>5000)
           update employee set salary= salary+3000 where current of Get_Data;
      end if;
    end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: you are right my friend, but i want to use continue statement becoz i know it works, but why this time it is not working.

Comment: Not the same in presence of NULL.